# PHP - string to 64bit number

Tags: php, twitter, 64-bit

I am playing with Twitter API. Some numbers (like Twitter ID) is really large such as 199693823725682700.

I've got this number as string format, and now I need to change it to just normal readable number, not like 1000xE09, because I need to substract -1 from that string-casted number. Then, I also need to send the number as string.

In sum, in PHP, how can I change the string a number, e.g.,  "199693823725682700" to another string "199693823725682699" (original number -1)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If BCMath is not available (it would be the preferable option if it is available) this function will decrement an arbitrarily sized integer stored as a string. There is no handling for floats or interpolation of scientific notation, it will only work with a string of decimal digits with an optional sign.

```
function decrement_string ($str) {

  // 1 and 0 are special cases with this method
  if ($str == 1 || $str == 0) return (string) ($str - 1);

  // Determine if number is negative
  $negative = $str[0] == '-';

  // Strip sign and leading zeros
  $str = ltrim($str, '0-+');

  // Loop characters backwards
  for ($i = strlen($str) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {

    if ($negative) { // Handle negative numbers

      if ($str[$i] < 9) {
        $str[$i] = $str[$i] + 1;
        break;
      } else {
        $str[$i] = 0;
      }

    } else { // Handle positive numbers

      if ($str[$i]) {
        $str[$i] = $str[$i] - 1;
        break;
      } else {
        $str[$i] = 9;
      }

    }

  }

  return ($negative ? '-' : '').ltrim($str, '0');

}
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/vzuemJ1D)

Comment: this works to me. bssub and others didn't work for my case. Thanks a lot for such clever code.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

BC Math module
Function http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.bcsub.php

Answer (score 1):

Apparently for now only way to deal with large integers in php is to use the `bcmath` extension. 64-bit integers are planed in PHP6.

Comment: There will be no PHP6. See 5.4 release notes.

Comment: @DmitryR: Do you have a link? The only thing I see in the [5.4.0 release announcement](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php) is "PHP 5.4 will be the last series to support Windows XP and Windows 2003. We will not provide binary packages for these Windows versions after PHP 5.4."

Answer (score 0):

You should try GMP with PHP,

here is the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php).